# Obfuscate PHP code (prevent source code viewing)

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP project using a PHP framework  which i would like sell.
Someone wants to test the code on their server first.

I do not want to give away the source.
So is it possible to obfuscate the code?
Or may be compile it?

My primary objective is, they should not be able to just take the code, once it is on their server and cheat me. Also I do not want them to handover the code to another developer and get it reverse engineered or changed.

I'm looking for a free solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Zend Guard to do the same so that it will encrypt your whole code and will compile it so that no one can use your source code. it works same as we do in JAVA as it create byte code in class files.

Go through this link [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)

Zend Guard, the most widely accepted PHP encoding and obfuscation product on the market

it will do following tasks for you:

Prevent reverse engineering & unauthorized modifications
Protect your code from unauthorized use

Comment: is it free? or do i need to buy?

Comment: http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/downloads

please check this as i believe its free for some trial or a long period. but be sure with this link please. thanks